# Package Tagging: missing logical operator AND

Tags: logic, tag

We would like to use package `tagging` with `xcookybooky` to list recipes into categories based on multiple parameters (tags). The desired outcome would be two sections of soups:

> a) soup AND meat

> b) soup AND vegetable.

The `tagging` package support sorting with multiple tags, which behaves as `OR` operator for multiple tags. This results in listing all recipes containing tag `soup` or `meat`.

I looked into to package itself, but I do not understand enough to redefine new command which would perform `AND` operation between two lists.

Original code

```
\newcommand\usetag[1]{%
  \def\do##1{\csdef{tagged@##1}{}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}}%
```

How would you apply a filter on multiple tags (`tag1 AND tag2`) to a list of tagged recipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want it is necessary to rewrite essential parts of `tagging.sty`, therefore I suggest to create a file `taggingx.sty` with the following contents.

```
% Copyright 2021 Gernot Salzer
% Extension of tagging.sty v1.1.0.1 by Brent Longborough
% For the license, see tagging.sty
% ------------------------------------------------------
\ProvidesPackage{taggingx}[2021/01/11]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox,verbatim}

\newcommand\usetag[1]{%
  \def\do##1{\csdef{tagged@##1}{}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}}%
\newcommand\droptag[1]{%
  \def\do##1{\csundef{tagged@##1}{}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}}%

\newcommand\numberOfTagsToMatch[1]{\def\@numberOfTagsToMatch{#1}}
\numberOfTagsToMatch{1}
\newcounter{tagsMatched}

\newcommand{\iftagged}[3]{%
  \setcounter{tagsMatched}{1}%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifcsname tagged@##1\endcsname
      \stepcounter{tagsMatched}%
    \fi
  }%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
  \ifnum\value{tagsMatched}>\@numberOfTagsToMatch
    \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \else
    \def\@tempa{#3}%
  \fi
  \@tempa
}
\newcommand{\tagged}[2]{\iftagged{#1}{#2}{}}
\newcommand{\untagged}[2]{\iftagged{#1}{}{#2}}

\newenvironment{taggedblock}[1]{%
  \tagged{#1}{%
    \let\comment\relax%
    \let\endcomment\relax%
  }%
  \comment\ignorespaces
}{%
  \endcomment\ignorespacesafterend
}
\newenvironment{untaggedblock}[1]{%
  \untagged{#1}{%
    \let\comment\relax
    \let\endcomment\relax
  }%
  \comment\ignorespaces
}{
  \endcomment\ignorespacesafterend
}

\DeclareOption*{\usetag{\CurrentOption}}
\ProcessOptions
```

This extension of the original package adds a command

```
\numberOfTagsToMatch{number}
```

which specifies the number of tags that have to be matched. The default is

```
\numberOfTagsToMatch{1}
```

which corresponds to the behavior of the original package.

To match two tags at the same time ('and' connective), define the tags and set this value to two.

```
\usetag{tag1,tag2}
\numberOfTagsToMatch{2}
```

**Example:** In the following document, all parts are included that are tagged with `soup` AND `meat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{taggingx}
\begin{document}
\usetag{soup,meat}
\numberOfTagsToMatch{2}

\begin{taggedblock}{soup,meat}
  Soup with meat.
\end{taggedblock}

\begin{taggedblock}{soup,vegetables}
  Soup with vegetables.
\end{taggedblock}

\begin{taggedblock}{soup,meat,vegetable}
  Soup with meat and vegetables.
\end{taggedblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]